# How to add an additional value to a Shopify checkout URL?

Tags: url, get, shopify

My client's live Shopify setup has a feature where a URL goes to a sort of "quick checkout" that allows a customer to quickly purchase a single item. The way it works is, you first visit a URL like this:

`https://site1.com/cart/xxxxxxxxxxx:y`

and then you are immediately redirected to a URL like this:

`https://www.site2.us/aaaaaaaa/checkouts/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb`

And then on that second URL you can fill out the checkout form to purchase a single item that is displayed there. Notice that the two URLs use a different domain name. The `x`'s are numbers, the `y` is a number. The `a`'s are numbers and the `b`'s are hexadecimal digits(0-9, a-f).

Is this a common/documented URL flow for a Shopify single item checkout setup?

What I need to do is add a value to the first URL so that it carries through to the second URL, eg:

`https://site1.com/cart/xxxxxxxxxxx:y/extra-val-here`
`https://www.site2.us/aaaaaaaa/checkouts/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb/extra-val-here`

And then if the second URL has the extra value I need to do something extra in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shopify has some information on how to do this here: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/cart/use-permalinks-to-preload-cart#conversion-tracking

To summarize, you can add a cart note and an arbitrary number of cart attributes to your link as query parameters to the end of your direct-buy link.

The structure of such a URL is thus:

```
https://[yourstore.com]/cart/[variant_id]:[quantity]?attributes[extra-category-1]=extra-val-1&attributes[extra-category-2]=extra-val-2&note=Sure%20why%20not
```

I just confirmed that this does indeed work by placing a test order this way on my dev store - if you're still having any trouble, let me know and we can dig deeper.

Comment: Note: The above link also gives details on how to set a number of other parameters that transfer to the checkout. Possible fields include discount codes, shipping information, referral information, etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that first `note` value seems like it will do the trick because I can still see it after the redirect. If `note` is present in the redirect/checkouts URL, how do I write some extra code to do something with the `note` value? Basically I need to set a flag in a remote MySQL database when the checkouts page is viewed with a `note` and when a purchase is completed with `note` in the URL.

Comment: Hmm. Do you have a Shopify Plus plan? If you do, you can create your own `layout/checkout.liquid` template file, where you can write your own javascript to make any code to use the note that you need.  Otherwise, you could write some custom code in the Admin > Settings > Checkout > Order Processing > Additional Scripts, which will have access to elements of the checkout object such as the note field, but I _think_ that those scripts only run once the customer reaches the Thank-You page.